# wp nav menu add image after specific LI

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-selectors

```
<div id="menubar">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CLIENTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CAREER</a></li>
            <li class="last-child"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- menubar -->
```

here  is my menu structure using wp_nav_menu , i can add images before or after li using 'link_before' =>. 
but i only want an image after my EVENTS li, how to do that?
please help,
thank you.

Comment: What type of image you are going to put? A border or some big image?

Comment: a small logo of maximum 20X20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specialty of WordPress menu is, each element in the menu will have a unique id. So just pick the unique id of item "EVENTS" and apply your image to it.

Use chrome inspect element or Firebug to take the Event menu's id

[**CHECK THIS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/m5beq/).

In this I put a unique id `menu-item-3` for EVENTS and put a background image with position right.

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... I hope this is what you want.

```
​$('#menu li:contains("EVENTS")')​​​​​​.after('<img src="Your img source" alt="ALT tag"/>')​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;​​​​​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QUDyz/2/)

Comment: Check the fiddle its working na... Give me your site link or post what you tried.

Comment: yes the fiddle is working and i google te code and your answer is right ,but its not working for me.i am working locally,`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#menubar ul li:last-child").addClass("last-child");//selecting last menu item contact us
 $('#menu-home li a:contains("EVENTS")')​​​​​​.after('<img src="http://localhost/DNA/wp-content/themes/DNA/images/logo.png" alt="ALT tag"/>')​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;
 });//main function ends

</script>`, here is my jquery